# How do you setup TLDDoc to create documentation for JSP TagLibs?

Tags: jsp, installation, taglib

A company I work for currently has several taglibs across multiple projects.  We use maven and hudson.  I've been tasked to find something that we can use to auto-generate documentation for our taglibs.  I've found [TLDDoc](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibrarydoc/tlddoc) but I haven't been able to find anything explaining how to set this up.  Please note, I'm not a Java Developer, I'm a UI Developer that works in JSP among other technologies.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute [TLDDoc](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibrarydoc/tlddoc) as maven plugin, you can do it e.g. like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateTldDoc</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                        <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
                        <mainClass>com.sun.tlddoc.TLDDoc</mainClass>
                        <arguments>                  
                            <argument>-doctitle</argument>
                            <argument>Whatever Taglib</argument>
                            <argument>-windowtitle</argument>
                            <argument>Whatever Taglib</argument>   
                            <argument>-d</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/tlddoc</argument>
                            <argument>src/main/resources/META-INF/something.tld</argument>
                            <argument>src/main/resources/META-INF/somethingelse.tld</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>taglibrarydoc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tlddoc</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had some similar requirement. What I did was to use an Ant script within the maven file, it would find all the TLD definition files under the projects I needed, and looped over each file and do something.

I needed to 2 outputs. HTML and DITA (technical documentation format, successor of DOCBOOK).

1. For each TLD, the TLDDoc would be invoked and to an output directory that would be the same.
2. An extra script executed an XSLT stylesheet that was transforming the TLD xml into DITA. From DITA I use the "DITA Open Toolkit" to output into PDF, and another type of HTML.

With maven you need to learn a little bit of ANT script, and know how to call java classes (TLDDOC) or the XSLT engine.

It was really cool, and quite flexible.

Comment: Forgot to mention. The TLDDoc can be found as a maven plug-in. See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibrarydoc/tlddoc